# Annotating a corpus for sentiment analysis using Stanford NLP

Tags: java, annotations, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I would like to manualy annotate a corpus to train the stanford core nlp parser for sentiment analysis.

Here are my questions:

- Is there any GUI Tool?
- Can someone confirm me that the tree to be annotated is shaped according to the syntax tree (and not the dependency one)?

Thank you